# LiveData из ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, архитектура

Принято наружу из ViewModel давать LiveData а не MutableLiveData. Как у вас это происходит?

Например, я делаю так:

```
private val _objectsState: MutableLiveData<ObjectListUIState> = MutableLiveData()
val objectsState: LiveData<ObjectListUIState> get() = _objectsState
```

Например, появляются всякие:

```
private val _mapBoundState: MutableLiveData<BoundBox> = MutableLiveData()
val mapBoundState: LiveData<BoundBox> get() = _mapBoundState

private val _bottomSheetVisibleState: MutableLiveData<Booleand> = MutableLiveData()
val bottomSheetVisibleState: LiveData<Booleand> get() = _bottomSheetVisibleState

private val _mapTileTypeState: MutableLiveData<TileType> = MutableLiveData()
val mapTileTypeState: LiveData<TileType> get() = _mapTileTypeState
```

и т.д. Можно как то по другому это делать? (чтобы кода по меньше)

Comment: я использую просто MutableLiveData чтобы не плодить лишний код. не выжу смысла в том чтобы она была приватной

Comment: понял, тоже так думал, но всякие best practices не дают покоя)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете использовать sealed class и постить состояния.

Пример:

```
sealed class State {
    data class DataLoaded(val data: List<YourData>) : State()
    data class Error(val error: Exception) : State()
    object Loading : State()
}
```

и создать одну LiveData

```
val stateLiveData = MutableLiveData<State>()
```

К примеру вы стартуете загрузку вы передаете

```
stateLiveData.post(State.Loading)
```

при получении данных

```
stateLiveData.post(State.Data(data))
```

Собственно во View у вас есть метод что-то вроде такого:

```
fun handleState(state: State){
    when (state){
        is Loading -> showLoader()
        is Error -> showError(state.error)
        is DataLoaded -> showData(state.data)
    }
}
```

Comment: мне кажется состояния лучше обрабатывать во ViewModel. любую логику лучше выносить туда

Comment: Если в состоянии нет логики кроме отображения UI, то я хз зачем это делать во ViewModel. Если же вы в каком-то состоянии начинаете к примеру загружать файл из сети, то стоит это состояние переработать

Comment: да, где это возможно использую такой подход. Но не всегда получается засунуть в sealed. У некоторых вообще есть такое понятие, что за состояние экрана отвечает один state, типа class ViewState(val objectsData: Any, val error: String?, val sheetVisible: Boolean, ...): State() и они просто гоняют этот state между View и ViewModel и просто меняют состояние этого state (но в таком случае при изменении любого из свойств state нужно перерисовать все элементы View, ну или как то проверять во View изменились данные определенных свойств  или нет)

Comment: Ну а по другому никак. Либо так как мы писали выше либо это вынести в Стейт. Куда ж вы переменные то денете?

Comment: Да я уж начал думать, может есть в котлин возможности о которых я не знаю)) Типа переопределить метод get у MutableLiveData и на выходе получать LiveData)) Похоже, кукан поехал))

Comment: Ну вы можете написать свой extension. Можете getter написать к каждой лайв дате

Comment: А как Вы у себя решаете кейсы типа дозагрузки данных? Выводите LoadingState в отдельный LiveData?

Comment: У меня в проекте в целом нет LiveData и сам я не сталкивался с таким. Но думаю, что вам нужно либо более подробно описывать стейт. Может быть прям State.Loading и в нем создавать поля вроде loaderMain, paginaionLoader. Ну или стейтов делать больше. Можно пойти вообще сторону MVI и там прям полностью описывать весь экран